# Get particular <a> tags that have a specific href

Tags: php, regex

My regex skills are a bit rusty. I'm developing in PHP and I'm trying to use regex to extract certain  tags that have a specific href, i.e:

```
    <a href=”javascript:void(0);” onclick=”window.open('.some-thing/utilities/words/hello','Words','
    toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes'); 
    return false;”>Hello</a>

    <a href=”www.google.com”>Google</a>
```

How can I extract one  tags that contain href=”javascript:void(0);”? Hope that makes sense. I could provide example of my regex used but I have used so many and they're just to messy.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: The mandatory comment here is "Don't use regex to parse HTML. Try SimpleXML or SAX. Also have a look at PHP's builtin XPath querying classes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Warning: you shouldn't parse HTML with a regex*

---

For the whole link:

```
/(<a\s[^>]*?href="javascript:void\(0\)\;?"[^>]*?>.*?<\/a>)/gsi
```

For content only:

```
/<a\s[^>]*?href="javascript:void\(0\)\;?"[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/a>/gsi
```

**[Try it yourself](http://regex101.com/r/pN2fF4/1)**

Comment: Thanks mate - This seems to do the job too: <a href=”javascript:void\(0\);”(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>

Comment: Yep, but it'll break if you've got an attribute before `href` (a class, for example)

Comment: So just look for javascript:void(0) since there are not other places that would be used

Comment: @mplungjan It depends of what OP is trying to achieve. If the goal is to count these links, your comment is perfectly valid, but what if he's trying to retrieve something ?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the whole `<a ...` tag or a certain part of it?